# rails migration doesn't update database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

I want to create association between client and project, client has_many projects and project belongs_to client. But migration doesn't create for example "client_id".

It is my models :

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :projects, dependent: :destroy
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :client
end
```

It is my migration files:

```
class CreateProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :projects do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.datetime :start_date
      t.datetime :end_date
      t.boolean :active

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateClients < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :clients do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Should I do it manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the reference in migration as well.  The reference is added to the table which has the foreign key.

```
class CreateProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :projects do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.datetime :start_date
      t.datetime :end_date
      t.boolean :active

      t.references :client # Add this line

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I did it, i also add add_index :projects, :client_id but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Depending on the current migration version, you might need to rollback and redo this migration.  Please keep in mind that doing so is going to delete all the records, so if you have any data you might want to consider backing the table up first.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already run the migration then, you could just add a new migration as

`rails generate migration AddClientToProjects client:references`

This will generate a migration as below:

```
class AddClientToProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :projects, :client, index: true
  end
end
```

and do `rake db:migrate`.

---

If you want to add the reference in the `CreateProjects` migration itself.

Then do the following:

Rollback the migration,if its already run

`rake db:rollback VERSION=version_number`

where,

Replace version_number with the version number mentioned in the migration filename.

For eg: If your migration filename is `20140125190622_create_projects.rb`
then command should be

```
rake db:rollback VERSION=20140125190622
```

Destroy the current migration using

`rails destroy migration CreateProjects`

and create it again using:

`rails generate migration CreateProjects name start_date:datetime end_date:datetime active:boolean client:references`

This will create a migration as follows:

```
class CreateProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :projects do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.datetime :start_date
      t.datetime :end_date
      t.boolean :active

      t.references :client, index:true # You could also add it manually to existing migration

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Run `rake db:migrate` after this.

Comment: But this won't help if `CreateProjects` has already been applied to a production database and the intent is to add the association as a new feature.

Comment: @muistooshort +1 I assumed that OP didn't run the migration. I would add a point for that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the solution to your current problem here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

your project migration needs a line t.integer :client_id

or t.references :client from vee should also do the trick